# reading a file in java and controlling an array list

Tags: java, arrays, reader

I know my code is not optimal and there is certainly a better way to write what I am trying to do than how I have it written.

I am trying to setup a reader so that it inserts information into an array list.  Right now my problem is that I cannot find out how to add an object to an array list only once.  The last object of the file is filling the empty spaces of the arrayList.

```
public void readCharacterFile() {

    String fileName = "C:/Users/brenton.reittinger/Desktop/characters.txt";
    String line = null;
    String fileContent = "";

    try {
        FileReader in = new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(in);

        while((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileContent = fileContent + line;
        }   

        bufferReader.close();

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Character character = new Character();
    Attributes attribute = new Attributes();

    character.setAttribute(attribute);

    String[] file = fileContent.split(":");

    int count = 0;          

    for (String fileSection : file) {
        if (fileSection.length() > 0) {
            if(count == 5) {
                character.getAttribute().setLevel(Integer.parseInt(fileSection));
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 4) {
                character.getAttribute().setExperience(Integer.parseInt(fileSection));
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 3) {
                character.getAttribute().setHealth(Integer.parseInt(fileSection));
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 2) {
                character.getAttribute().setAttack(Integer.parseInt(fileSection));
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 1) {
                character.setRace(fileSection);
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 0) {
                character.setName(fileSection);
                count++;
            }   
        }           
    }
    user.addCharacterToList(character);
}
```

Comment: what is your question ? how to avoid adding the same character twice ?

Comment: see `(Array)List.contains` and `Set`

Comment: `Files.readAllLines` just a helpful piece of code to read your file. No different really though

Answer (score -1):

Why not using a java `Set` instead? Sets guarantee that each object instance can only occur once.